# responsive navigation using query

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a responsive navigation built using `ul li`. It hides on smaller screens and there is a toggle button using jQuery. The problem is that the `li` items on the menu won't close after clicking on one of them, and I can't make it toggle back up when clicking away.

Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/rondoe/pen/mOPzyV) of what I have got so far.

```
<nav>
    <span class="nav-btn"></span>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">What</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Where</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">When</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Why</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'helvetica neue', helvetica;
}
.nav {
    background-color: #4f4f4f;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
.nav > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.nav > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #fff;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .nav {
        text-align: left;
        display: none;
    }
    .nav > li {
        display: block;
    }
    .nav-btn {
        display: block;
        background-color: #333;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    .nav-btn:before {
        content: "Menu";
    }
```

```js
$("span.nav-btn").click(function(event){
    $('ul.nav').slideToggle();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() > 600) {
        $('ul.nav').removeAttr('style');  
    }
});
```

Please advise. It is very frustrating.

Comment: Is your CSS code complete? Reformatting it led to unclosed parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the updated code in your Js section, it will work as per your expectation.

```
$("span.nav-btn").click(function(event){
    $('ul.nav').slideToggle();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
   if ($(window).width() > 600) {
       $('ul.nav').removeAttr('style');  
   }
});

//Code need to be add,

$(".nav li").click(function(){
    if($('ul.nav').css('display') == 'block'){
          $('ul.nav').slideUp("slow");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for trying to help.
The problem with this solution is that the ul.nav is hiding on click when the screen size is bigger and the display is inline-block

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for two separate behaviors.

1. When clicking the menu item you need it to collapse.
2. When clicking anywhere else on the document, you need the menu to collapse if its open.

Hence, You will be needing two events, one bound to the `document` and other to the menu item to get the desired results.

```
$(document).click(function(event) { 
   if(!$(event.target).closest('#bloopy').length) {
      $('ul.nav').slideUp();
   }        
});
$(".nav li").click(function(){
   $('ul.nav').slideUp("slow");
});
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/MohdAbdulMujib/pen/PbzdzL)**